# Bottom border for text field doesn’t appear

Tags: ios, swift, border

I tried to add a bottom border to my text field but it doesn't work. I know that there are similar questions out there but none of those answers help. Also, I removed this line of code below and tried because there is no border by default, it still doesn't work:

```
username.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.none
```

Here is the whole code:

```
class SignUpScreen: UIViewController {

    let username = UITextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(username)

        // Background color
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        username.placeholder = "Name"
        username.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.none

        let bottomLine = CALayer()
        bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - 1, width: view.frame.width, height: 1.0)
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        username.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)

        username.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        username.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        username.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        username.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        username.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me out! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is what you were missing: You were using the main view's frame for creating the frame of your layer. You must use the text field.**

Also first draw your text field properly with constraints then add layer to text field.

In **viewDidLoad** your content view is loaded to main memory. There is no frame assignment in that method. So use **viewWillAppear** or **viewDidAppear**.

Now when your view will appear every time a new TextField & a layer will be added. So you need to make a check to restrict that behaviour. E.g **if a text field is already added to your view then don't add.**

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    view.addSubview(username)

    /*
     * Create the text field
     */
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    username.placeholder = "Name"
    username.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.none
    username.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    username.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    username.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    username.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    username.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    /*
     * Here add the shap layer
     */
    let bottomLine = CALayer()

    /*
     * Here is what you were missing.
     * You were using the main view's frame instead of your textfield
     */
    bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: username.bounds.height - 1, width: username.bounds.width, height: 1.0)
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    username.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
}
```

Comment: Hey I am new to swift and I don't exactly know what you have done here, can I know where you learned all this? Is there a site or video link that you can provide? Thanks!

Comment: BTW Can I add this to another text field? I have a text field called password, adding this: password.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine). Will this work?

Comment: No you need to create a new layer with the frame of your password field. If you will use the same, it will be added on your username field.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - 1, width: view.frame.width, height: 1.0)
```

you must use `username.bounds`, instead of `view.frame`

Comment: put layer's frame update to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you, mind explaining a little bit?

Comment: during `viewDidLoad`, `username` has initial frame. then it will update it's frame to match auto layout constraints. So you should updated sublayers frames manually, after layout finished. Alternatively, try to run code inside `viewDidAppear` to see if it help at all

Comment: Yes it is correct but before adding the layer to some view, we have to layout that view first. Means after constrains we can add the layer. @AbdullahAjmal please see my answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56540179/6197968

Answer (score 0):

rather than adding a **layer** maybe you should add your **border** as `UIView` and bring it to *top* also set your `textField` `bgColor` as `clearColor`:

```
     class SignUpScreen: UIViewController {

        let username = UITextField()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            view.addSubview(username)

            // Background color
            view.backgroundColor = .white

            username.placeholder = "Name"
            username.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.none

            // make sure your textField doesn't have back ground
            username.backgroundColor = .clear

            let bottomLine = UIView()
            bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - 1, width: view.frame.width, height: 1.0)
            bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

            // be sure you bring it to top
            self.view.layer.insertSublayer(bottomLine, at:0)

            username.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            username.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            username.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            username.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
            username.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

         }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(3.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textFieldOutlet.frame.size.height - width, width: textFieldOutlet.frame.size.width, height: textFieldOutlet.frame.size.height)

    border.borderWidth = width
    textFieldOutlet.layer.addSublayer(border)
    textFieldOutlet.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func bottomBorderTextField(_ textField: UIView, color: UIColor) {
        // For Bottom Border
        let bottomLayer = CALayer()
        let frame = viewType.frame
        bottomLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.height - 1, width: frame.width - 2, height: 0.5)
        bottomLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        viewType.layer.addSublayer(bottomLayer)
    }
```

- In **viewDidload()**

```
 self.bottomBorderTextField(self.txtField, color: yourTextColor)
```